# AWS ECS Assumed Role using CloudFormation. Where to get assumed role for Docker micro service deployed in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I need to restrict bucket from using cloudformation with setting assumed role and iam role in principle  using CFN ?

Answer (score 0):

You might need the environment variable as mentioned in the [documetation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html).

> **ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE=true**
>
> Enables IAM roles for tasks for containers with the bridge and default network modes.
>
> **ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE_NETWORK_HOST=true**
>
> Enables IAM roles for tasks for containers with the host network mode. This variable is only supported on agent versions 1.12.0 and later.